# JQuery tabs disordering when add

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Run code follow and click in last tab of first rows tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/pKcJp/

```
<html>
</html>
<button id="addspan">Add tabs</button>
<div id="wrap">
    <ul></ul>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
$('#wrap').tabs();
$('#addspan').click(function () {
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 1, 1);

    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 2, 2);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 3, 3);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 4, 4);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 5, 5);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 6, 6);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 7, 7);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 8, 8);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 9, 9);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 10, 10);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 11, 11);
    $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 12, 12);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 13, 13);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 14, 14);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 15, 15);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 16, 16);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 17, 17);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 18, 18);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 18, 18);
            $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + 18, 18);
});
});
</script>
```

See that have an disordering tabs.

This problem not occurs if Jquery version is changed to 1.7.2 and jquery-ui to 1.8.18(changed in menu)

Any Idea?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, please update your question and give us a better explanation of what is going on.

Comment: I don't see the problem appear on any version of jQuery, the order is good (from 1 to 18).

Answer (score 3):

This is because the jQuery UI CSS adds it's own class to the active tab and inserts a margin-bottom rule. Add your own to override it.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pKcJp/1/)**

Comment: Great!
But I'm not do make it in my real project. My css file is generated by:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Even if you're using the jQuery UI themeroller, you can override it as I've shown.

Comment: Really. I apply this code in "style" tag in my .gsp file (grails) but not worked :( . I Removed css import and worked, but I can't remove this css.

Comment: Make sure the above modification comes after your other CSS.

Comment: For warranty I added at the end of the css file. No sucess :(